# Spring-kafka Integration : Changing ConsumerConfig property without restarting applications

Tags: spring-kafka

I am trying to change ConsumerConfig properties by making change in a property file, which will be watched by @scheduled method( this will look for change in any property value and re-initialize the consumer after updating container factory bean instance picked from application context).

For example: If new broker is added to cluster, I would simply update broker list in property file.

Answer (score 1):

The `KafkaConsumer` and its `ConsumerConfig` comes from the `DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory` into the `KafkaMessageListenerContainer`.
The `DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory` is injected with the `Map` of configs for the consumer. I think this is exactly the place where you should consider to change properties from your `@Scheduled` method. After changing them you should `stop()` listener container(s) and `start()` again - a new `KafkaConsumer` will be created based on fresh configs.

However a `consumerGroupId` indeed should be changed via `ContainerProperties`.
For this purpose there is just enough to change it via `MessageListenerContainer.getContainerProperties().setGroupId(String groupId)`.

Comment: Thanks Artem, but cant find getContainerProperties() on MessageListenerContainer object . I am using 'spring-kafka:1.0.2.RELEASE' and kafka 0.10

Comment: Oh! That's too old! Consider to use `AbstractMessageListenerContainer` then

Comment: I recommend upgrading to at least 1.3.3 (current version is 2.1.4). Starting with 1.3, a much simpler threading model is used (thanks to KIP-62).

Comment: Thanks Artem and Gary Sir